# Why am I getting this error when trying to install wine 1.4?

Tags: apt, wine

Can any one tell me what this error means? I am trying to install wine 1.4 but it keeps failing with this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but 1.16.1.2ubuntu7 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
     Depends: libgettextpo0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa3) but 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa3 is to be installed
     Depends: binfmt-support (>= 1.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 3):

> `Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa3) but 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa3 is to be installed`

It looks like you're trying to install an outdated version of Wine from some PPA. Please remove the PPA from Software Sources, update, and then try to install Wine again.